# How to detect a page and modify a class based on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a bar with 4 pieces to it. Each piece will lead to and be a different page. What I am wanting to do is if the user is on page `A` for example, I want the background for that `service-specificBar-tab` to be a certain color. For example sake, red. Then if the user is on `B` for the background of that `service-specificBar-tab` to be another different color, ie: purple.

So basically, how would I go about detecting which page the user is on and making the `service-specificBar-tab` be a certain color? OR is there a different way to do this without detecting a page?

```css
#gray {
 background: #f9f9f9;
 width: 100%;
 height: 700px;
 position: relative;
}
#service-specificBar-container {
 position: relative;
 top: 300px;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 25px 0;
}
#service-specificBar {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
.service-specificBar-tab {
 width: 25%;
 height: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0px;
}
.service-specificBar-tab:nth-child(2) {
 background: blue;
}
.service-specificBar-tab:nth-child(4) {
 background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="gray">
  <div id="service-specificBar-container">
   <div id="service-specificBar"><div class="service-specificBar-tab">A
    </div><div class="service-specificBar-tab">B
    </div><div class="service-specificBar-tab">C
    </div><div class="service-specificBar-tab">D
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the actual url with `window.location.href`, so then you just make a switch to change the color of a certain div. I would also recommend, although it's not necessary, to add an `id` to each service-specificBar-tab.

Example:

```
switch( window.location.href ){
    case "http://example.com/myFirstPage":
        $("#firstItemId").addClass("active");
        break;

    case "http://example.com/mySecondPage":
        $("#secondItemId").addClass("active");
        break;
}
```

And if you want it to be a different color for each active tab define it in your css

```
#firstItemId.active {
    background-color: red;
    /* active css */
}
```

If there is the possibility of arriving there with a hash on the url, you can remove it like this:

```
var url = window.location.href.split("#")[0];
```

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by this "If there is the possibility of arriving there with a hash on the url, you can remove it like this:"?

Comment: Am I able to do shorthand with this? `case "/myFirstPage":` ?

Comment: For example, when I came to your comment the url was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35872850/how-to-detect-a-page-and-modify-a-class-based-on-it/35872992#comment59410960_35872992 , you can see the final section "#comment59410960_35872992" which makes reference to your comment, if we remove that part the url would still the same.

Comment: For using just the path i.e. `case "/myFirstPage":` use `window.location.pathname`instead of `window.location.href`. The part after the hash wouldn't be a problem here

Comment: I just tried it out and it works great. Thanks for the help and good answer!